# localStorage to save an object without beeing able to read its content?

Tags: javascript, json, html, eval, local-storage

I found the nice "localStorage" function of HTML5. As I understood it only allows to save strings so we need to use eval()/JSON to save objects/functions as well.

Now I want to know if it is possible to save a string that can be excecuted with eval() but can't be read.

So I want to use localStorage.setItem only one time, disable localStorage.getItem completly and replace it with something like "localStorage.evalItem".

This would be a safe way against XSS/MITM (after the functions have been saved).

EDIT:

Details: The idea was to save something similar to:

```
function aes_encode(string) {
   var salt='unique_salt';
   // aes encoding...
   return salty_encoded_string
}
```

in a non (source) readable storage hostet at the visitor side.

And as the unique salt is created once for every visitor it would be possible to verify the client data.

But as James and nwellcome (thx!) said its not possible to avoid reading the source.

I don't think downvoting is correct or was the question so unclear?!

Comment: _a string that can be excecuted with eval() but can't be read_ - there is no such thing.  You can make it hard to read but never impossible.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As a rule of thumb, to prevent XSS, don't trust data coming from clients.

This includes anything in local storage. LocalStorage does not have an HTTPOnly flag like cookies to make it inaccessible to Javascript. Even if it did, the user could use a debug tool to modify it. For this reason I would warn against using `eval()` on anything you get from localStorage. I encourage you to use [JSON sans eval](http://code.google.com/p/json-sans-eval/) to read JSON objects and to not use it for functions at all. You should be able to accomplish anything you would be able to by putting functions in localStorage by instead using appropriate caching and [offline applications](http://www.w3.org/TR/html5/offline.html#offline).

As an aside, the way you described it

```
localStorage.evalItem(key).toSource() == localStorage.getItem(key);
```

So I don't believe your approach could prevent anyone from reading if it could eval.

Comment: I won't trust. The idea was to save `function aes_encode(var salt='unique_string';return salty_encoded_string)` in a non (source) readable storage hostet at the visitor side. And the unique string is created once for every visitor so its possible to verify the client data. But as you said its not possible to avoid reading the source. Bummer!